# All mobiscroll components for verson 2.17 for angular js stopped working on Android 10

Tags: android, angularjs, mobiscroll

Mobiscroll for Angular JS Select Lists and Date Pickers previously functioning on Android 9 but not working on Android 10

They open but Cancel and OK buttons not functioning. Selecting dates is not possible in Date 
pickers.

This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

No errors in developer tools console. Anybody else seeen this problem?

html page:

```
<select id="userName" ng-model="currentUserName" mobiscroll-select 
mobiscroll-options="{theme:'ios',lang:'sv'}" >
    <option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in userNames">{{ user }} . 
</option>
</select>
```

app.js :

```
angular.module('ourAppApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'mobiscroll-select'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
     controller: 'MainCtrl',
     controllerAs: 'main'
   })
   .when('/about', {
     templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
     controller: 'AboutCtrl',
     controllerAs: 'about'
   })
   .otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
    }); 
 });
```

controller for html page:

```
        angular.module('ourAppApp')
          .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {       
            this.userNames = [
              'Big G',
              'Psycho Z',
              'Uncle P'
            ];

            $scope.currentUserName =  'Big G';
            $scope.userNames =  this.userNames;

          });
```

Comment: can you add a piece of code?

Comment: updated with code